# Character degrees of a finite group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group, $R(G)$ be the solvable radical of $G$, and $G/R(G)$ be an almost simple group with socle $S\cong PSL_2(3^p)$, where $p$ is an odd prime. Also let $[G/R(G):S]=p$ and $\theta$ be a $G$-invariant complex irreducible character of $R(G)$ which is not extendible to $G$. What is the set of degrees of irreducible characters of $G$ lying over $\theta$.

Thanks.

Comment: The character degrees of ${\rm SL}(2,3^p)$ are going to be very relevant here

Comment: Of faithful characters, that is

Comment: @GeoffRobinson, could you please explain more?

Comment: @Geoff Robinson, could you please explain more?

Comment: You need to construct a central extension ${\hat G}$ of $G$ such that $\theta$ extends to a character of ${\hat G}$. This really comes from a central extension of $G/R(G)$ and that central extension will have ${\rm SL}(2,3^{p})$ as its unique component.